# Debugging Chrome Tab Crash

Tags: windows, google-chrome, crash

**The Problem**

I there is there internal web application that is crashing if you constantly switch back and forth between any pages.  This error show up in the creation of items as they involves several pages.  It is also preceeded for me (other have not notice this issue) with text display issues (text on top of each other, icon fonts not showing up, etc...).  If you hit the reload button on the error page, that page loads up fine.

This error seems to only have in Chrome on Windows after about 4-5 mins of constantly loading pages.  I have tried FireFox on Windows for over 10 minutes without issue and Chrome on Mac OS  X for over 10 minutes without issue.

The one thing I notices that I though might be the issue was that the memory usage kept increase with Chrome on Windows.  It would start at about 30MB and then general crash around 70MB-80MB however I have notices most site in chrome on windows do this so I am not so sure about it being related.

**What I have tried**

I have tried a number of different thing to figure out the issue,

I first tried to enable crash logging through chrome itself however that seems to only send the crash data to google and I just have access to the ID.  The crash folder has nothing useful to read, the only file data is unreadable in a text error.

I have also tried to run chrome with logging enable and read the logs from Sawbuck but again nothing useful.

The last thing I tried is to use WinDbg.exe with chrome and the only errors I get that don't seem normal (unlike the symbol not found errors) and that happen right before the crash page with the sad folder are these:

```
(5c4.76c): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
eax=00000000 ebx=00000002 ecx=10a70380 edx=00000000 esi=10a70380 edi=00baf980
eip=6c2104f3 esp=0019d260 ebp=0019d27c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
chrome_6bde0000!ovly_debug_event+0x40f41e:
6c2104f3 8b10            mov     edx,dword ptr [eax]  ds:002b:00000000=????????
3:050> g

(5c4.76c): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000002 ecx=10a70380 edx=00000000 esi=10a70380 edi=00baf980
eip=6c2104f3 esp=0019d260 ebp=0019d27c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
chrome_6bde0000!ovly_debug_event+0x40f41e:
6c2104f3 8b10            mov     edx,dword ptr [eax]  ds:002b:00000000=????????
```

I can keep pressing f5 and these errors message just repeat.  These make no sense and the only thing the looks like something I would reqconize is:

```
mov     edx,dword ptr [eax]
```

Which looks like assembly code.

**Am I missing any other ways to debug a chrome tab crash on windows?**

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with changes made in chrome as version 28.0.1500.95 works fine but starting with version 29.0.1547.62, this issue occurs.

The issue seems to go away with the current canary build with is at version 31.0.1650.2 so I guess an upcoming release (not sure which one) should fix this issue.